# Почему в командной строке при запуске файла через команду python3 выводится слово Python, а не выполняется код программы?

Tags: python, windows, cmd

Есть файл hello.py с таким кодом:

```
print("Hello World")
print(2+2)
```

При запуске файла через консоль Windows 11 с помощью команды python всё работает правильно. Но если заменить команду python на python3, то вместо кода консоль просто выводит слово Python (то же самое выводится при вводе команды python3 --version), а при запуске команды отдельно от файла (т.е. если просто написать в консоль python3), меня перекидывает на страничку в Windows Store с предложением скачать python 3.11 (на компьютере стоит версия 3.11.4). Это конечно далеко не самая необходимая вещь, но мне всё же хотелось бы понять, почему консоль выполняет именно это, а не выдаёт какую-нибудь ошибку (т.к. из того, что я нашел, Windows как-будто не поддерживает команду python3). Заранее спасибо за объяснение.

Comment: Под Windows не нужно использовать python3 в командной строке. Это нужно только на Linux системах, где обычно установлено две версии: python 2.* и python 3.*, и ранее просто python означало именно python2.

Answer (score 0):

Если перейти по `C:\Users\Имя пользователя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python3xx` этому пути, то можно увидеть только `python.exe` поэтому windows не знает какой файл запускать. Если вы хотите использовать команду python3 продублируйте файл python.exe и переименуйте в `python3.exe`. Windows store открывается потому-то windows, имеет фальшивые файлы которые записаны в Path.

Comment: О, теперь понятно. Спасибо большое